# YugabyteDB showing incorrect SST Files usage

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm loading data into one table and see this on tables view on web console

```
Total: 2.54G
Consensus Metadata: 154.7K
WAL Files: 15.00G
SST Files: -12.46G
SST Files Uncompressed: 4.00G
```

Why is there a negative value for SST Files?
YugabyteDB version is 2.6.7.0 in a single node database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in the 2.8 branch. Specifically this commit: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/commit/a8152fa9a98fce7eb37cd6c87244ed7bd29a5965